# realloc function problem in Visual Studio

Tags: c

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d313h.jpg)
I have a problem with the reservation of the second element with the realloc function, as it is not reserved, unlike the rest of the elements that are reserved normally

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main() {
    int max, value, n = 0;
    int* feld = NULL;
    printf("enter max: ");
    scanf("%d", &max);
    do {
        printf("\nenter value: ");
        scanf("%d", &value);
        if (value >= 0) {
            feld = realloc(feld, sizeof(int));
            *(feld + n) = value;
            n++;
        }
        else {
            break;
        }

    } while (n < max);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        printf("\n%d", *(feld + i));
    }
    
}
```

When entering values, it exits when a negative value is entered or the maximum limit is reached

Comment: Don't post pictures of text, post text as text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to specify the correct size to `realloc`.

This reallocates each time the same size, which is rather pointless:

```
realloc(feld, sizeof(int))
```

Then you write beyond the allocated size which yields in *undefined behaviour*.

But actually you need to allocate each time space for one more `int`:

```
realloc(feld, sizeof(int) * (n + 1))
```

Read closely the [documentation of `realloc`](https://cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/realloc/?kw=realloc).

---

**Bonus information**

Don't use `*(feld + n)` but rather `feld[n]` which is the usual way.

---

**Bonus**

Idiomatic way to write the same code. Disclaimer: there are no error checks for brevity).

```
int main() {
  int max, value, n = 0;
  int* feld = NULL;
  printf("enter max: ");
  scanf("%d", &max);

  for (n = 0; n < max; n++) {
    printf("\nenter value: ");
    scanf("%d", &value);

    if (value < 0)
      break;
  
    feld = realloc(feld, sizeof(int) * (n + 1));
    feld[n] = value;
  } 

  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
  {
    printf("\n%d", feld[i]);
  }
}
```